# Дата окончания выборов модератора не локализована в блоке предстоящих событий

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, выборы, даты

В блоке предстоящих событий (он же, важное) не локализована дата окончания выборов:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: К следующим выборам надеюсь починят?

Comment: @AK при условии, что это будет кому-нибудь нужно (и не надейтесь)

Comment: О, ты первый заметил :) А я только сделал скриншот и собрался постить вопрос)))

Comment: @AK во, как бывает! Лишь бы следующих выборов не ждать! ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Спасибо за сообщение. У нас всё ещё остаётся небольшое число мест, где забыли что-то локализовать. Почти готово...

---

Thanks for reporting. We do still have a small number of places where we missed localising something. Getting there...

Comment: Thanks for fixing. What tool did you use: google-translate or Nicolas Chabanovsky?

Comment: Chrome, right click -> Translate to English :P

Comment: BTW, do you have any plans to use local specific date format here? Related [FR on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290392/339911).

Comment: IIRC, those are... a bit more complicated. Rendering happens in client side, I think (deep inside the library we use). I could be wrong. I'll take a look.

Comment: Current string is [`ends $when$`](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40263530?key=af40cff18505e90f6d047ba73e542745), hence impossible to change order here as you said on MSE for other strings.

Comment: OK, I don't really understand the need/context here. What's not working right here?

Comment: Currently date here looks as `окт 24`, but in Russian more suitable is `24 окт`. If `$when$` could be splitted to `$day$ $short_month$` we could change the order in translation.